# Need help subnetting a network for specific numbers of hosts?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, cidr

The issue below is entirely for revision/practice purposes and not homework. I'm just trying to wrap my head around how I would answer this as it could show up in an exam.

I have a problem where I'm given the base address `172.16.10.0 /22`

I need to create an IP address scheme where the network contains equal sized subnets of up to 120 hosts each.

I have some experience with subnetting an address into a particular number of subnets, but I've never had to do it where the subnets must support a particular number of hosts (in this case 120).

From the `172.16.10.0 /22` I can tell it's a class B address, then with 10 host bits 2 to the power of 10 minus 2 makes 1,022 possible hosts.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to start but any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: 120 hosts fits in a /25, and you can fit 8 of those in a /22  ( where 8 == 2 ^ (25 - 22) )

Comment: and BTW, this is completely off topic here

Comment: You are really asking this on the wrong SE site. It is better suited to [networkengineering.se], where, if you search, you will find [this excellent answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) that tells you how to do this. By the way, network classes are dead, and they have been for over 20 years. In 1993, RFCs 1518 and 1519 killed network classes with CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Please let network classes rest in peace. They are not used in modern networking.

Comment: @RonMaupin last I heard they're still used in CCIE exams :(

Comment: Well, you heard wrong. Back around the turn of the century, they were still in CCNA exams, but I have not ever seen them in the CCIE exams.

Comment: Apologies for posting in the wrong place. I wasn't aware of the Network Engineering section. With regards to classful addressing they were in my CCNA exam as well as my topics list for my university exam. They still teach it but of course we're taught that CIDR is the better option.

Comment: The only thing classes are still used for is to name 10...., 172.... and 192.... networks, other than that, it's dead like Ron said.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to remember that each /24 has 256 addresses (minus  network and broadcast). A /23 has 2 x /24 and one /22 has 2 x /23.

Each /24 if divided in 2 means 2 x /25 . If one /24 has 256 addresses, the /25 has 128, which is closer to what you need.

So 1 /22 = 2 /23 = 4 /24 = 8 /25 .

So you could use 8 x /25, each with a max of 128 addresses or 126 host addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it makes more sense now. I also found dividing the 1,024 hosts by 120 gave me 8 also. 2 to the power of 3 gives me eight so I would need 3 more host bits to make it /25 instead of /23.